# How can I find the thread of emails which include a given email?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

In Outlook, I found an email in my Sent folder that i sent to a person. How can I find the thread of emails which including the email in my Sent folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the email you're interested in, select "Find Related" and then the sub-option "Messages in this Conversation".

[image]

Outlook will now show you all the messages in this conversation, including your own.